# Unauthorized to access @me/settings

Tags: oauth-2.0, httprequest, discord, bearer-token

When I try to acces [`/api/users/@me/settings`](https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me/settings) via a `GET`, `POST` or `PATCH`, I always get a `{"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0}`. When I acces [`/api/users/@me`](https://discordapp.com/api/users/@me) with the Authorization header set to `Bearer <my-acces-key>`, I do get a 200 OK response, with my data. I have the `identify` and the `rpc.api` scopes. Do I have to set other scopes?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to gain an Oauth-2 token, you have to take a look at the offical documentation here: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2
Right now, you probably won't be able to do RPC requests as you have to apply for RPC access by submitting your application to Discord and they have to approve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use my own Discord token not the application key. Check out how to get it [here](https://discordhelp.net/discord-token).

MAKE SURE NOT TO SHARE YOUR DISCORD TOKEN!

Comment: btw this is probably against the [Terms of Service](https://discordapp.com/terms)

Comment: I think the author talks about the legal Oauth2-API, not about selfbots.